# Find: $\mathcal{L}^{-1} \left(\frac{2s}{(s^2 + 4)^2}\right)$

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform

I tried to compute the inverse Laplace transform: $\mathcal{L}^{-1} \left(\frac{2s}{(s^2 + 4)^2}\right)$
By decomposing the fraction to the form of
$\frac{As+B}{s^2+4}+\frac{Cs+D}{(s^2+4)^2}$ , but this lead nowhere. Any help, thank you all.

Answer (score 4):

$$\mathcal{L}\{\sin{(at)}\}=\frac{a}{s^2+a^2}$$
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}\{t\sin{(at)}\}
&=-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}s}\mathcal{L}\{\sin{(at)}\}\\
&=\frac{2as}{(s^2+a^2)^2}\\
\end{align}$$
$$\therefore\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{2s}{(s^2+4)^2}\right\}=\frac12t\sin{(2t)}$$